# How to use scss in an input field

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a styling class called `section-changing-input` which contains a subclass Input. I want the input to have a red border.
However, when I import this class into my `<input>` element, nothing is displayed.

How do I write the styling class correctly in my div so that I get a red border?

```
import React from 'react'
import './style/General.scss'


function General() {



    return (
        <div>
                        <div className="field">
                            <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                <input className="section-changing-input" type="text" value="Hello" />
                                <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                                    <i className="fas fa-futbol"></i>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default General
```

General.scss

```
section-changing-input {
    input {
        border-color: crimson !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured your react app to work with scss

Comment: Yes, I have configured my React app.

Comment: You need to add the `className` to the top `div` not to the `input` itself that's what you have written in scss and a below answer says you are missing `.` from your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed dot for the parent class. Also since the main class is placed for the input tag itself, so there is no child element or class required

```
.section-changing-input {
  border-color: crimson !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's right, but the problem remains that the class input from the scss does not allow a border to be displayed in red